# Base_link frame is not connected to odom frame

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, frame, base-link

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo

I used the following block of code to publish the transformation of base_link frame and odom frame:

```
geometry_msgs::TransformStamped odom_trans;
    odom_trans.header.stamp = current_time;
    odom_trans.header.frame_id = "odom";
    odom_trans.child_frame_id = "base_link";

    odom_trans.transform.translation.x = x;
    odom_trans.transform.translation.y = y;
    odom_trans.transform.translation.z = 0.0;
    odom_trans.transform.rotation = odom_quat;

    //send the transform
    odom_broadcaster.sendTransform(odom_trans);
```

Also, I used this launch file to publish the other frames:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" args="0 0 1 0 0 0 1 base_link camera_link 100" />
</launch>
```

When the robot start moving I run rviz and it shows the odom frame moving, but the base_link and camera_link are fixed in their initial position. I think I missed something but I don't know what is it.

UPDATE:

1. current_time is set inside the loop `while(nodehandle.ok())`    and is set to `current_time = ros::Time::now();`
2. `odom_broadcaster` is created outside the loop and at the beginning of the main as  `tf::TransformBroadcaster odom_broadcaster;`
3. This is running live
4. When I run `rosrun tf tf_echo odom base_link` it shows values like:

   At time 1428335473.731

   - Translation: [-0.338, 1.148, 0.000]
   - Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.295, 0.955]
     in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 0.600]
     At time 1428335474.787
   - Translation: [-1.613, 3.059, 0.000]
   - Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.223, 0.975]
     in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 0.449]
5. This is my tf tree:

[image: tf tree]

Also I have this transformation in the launch file:  `<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" args="0 0 1 0 0 0 1 base_link camera_link 100" />`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206649/base_link-frame-is-not-connected-to-odom-frame/) by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-04-05

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-04-06**:
When do you set the `current_time` variable, and with what value? Also, where are you creating `odom_broadcaster`? Are you running this live or against a bag file? What happens if you run `rosrun tf tf_echo odom base_link`?

**Comment by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on 2015-04-06**:
please find the update in the question

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2015-04-06**:
what does `roswtf` tell you?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-04-06**:
Wait, are you expecting `odom` and  `base_link` to move with one another? `odom` is a world-fixed frame, and `base_link` is attached to the robot. As your robot moves through the world, they will not remain "with" one another in `rviz`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you solve?
Be sure in your code to update all frames with the most recent time stamp. I mean, every loop you should be sure that the broadcast information is updated:

```
odom_trans.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
```

From the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher) you see that that line of code is inside a loop. maybe you forgot to update all the frames for the camera and so on...
I hope I helped you.

Regards

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2015-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0